# How does one call the y axis of a waveform?

Tags: audio, terminology

In many audio applications one can find a waveform representation, but the y-axis normally is never labelled.

**Now, if you would plot your own waveform and wanted to label it, what would be a correct label for the y-axis?**

For me the y-axis represents vibrations, but for "vibration" or "relative vibration" as label sounds strange, I am also not 100% sure, if vibration is the correct term. Thank you for any hint!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've marked in the image is the ***scale***. This will labeled with the  [***unit of measurement***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_measurement). This is typically decibel (dB), percent (%) or volt (V).

The y axis represents the [***amplitude***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude).

Comment: the problem with the term "amplitude" is, that amplitude is only the maximum of a vibration. scale is probably not wrong, but isn't it a little bit too trivial? ;-) Still open for new terms :-) And thanks, doc ;-)

Comment: A dB scale always looks different from what's asked about here, because it's logarithmic. — @stefan.at.wpf: amplitude is not necessarily just the maximum of a vibration, it can also mean the... well, _amplitude_ at any single point in a waveform.

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf You didn't get it. - You have to understand, the waveform represents a lot of values. These values were measurements within a time frame. Every single value is the amplitude for a specific moment. So the waveform represents a continuous **series of amplitude measurements**. - Second: You joker. I didn't wrote you should label it "scale". I wrote it will be **labeled with the unit of measurement**.

Comment: Thank you Doktor, I somehow managed to read this simple answer wrong ): Sorry. leftaroundabout and Doktor, thank you for the "amplitude at any single point in a waveform", that's a neat logical "trick". So I am now happy with the term amplitude :-)

Comment: Vibration is frequency, so if you want to see a snapshot of the vibrations then you should switch to spectral or FFT view.

Comment: doensn't the waveform represents the sum of all frequencies and therefore also the sum of all vibrations? (which is again a vibration?)

Comment: That's principally correct.

Answer (score 3):

X is time

Y is amplitude, volume, voltage, dB or pressure, depending on exactly where you are measuring,  but they can be considered equivalent in an audio scenario.